# Search in Laravel 6

Tags: mysql, laravel, search, eloquent

I have a problem with my search method in Laravel 6,

My database have a table products and my search method look for the `slug` attribute to do the trick, the problem is when I search for a product name in other order.

Have this product 'FONE XIAOMI', and If I search like this way, returns me the product correctly.
But If I search for 'XIAOMI FONE', give me no results.
What I'm doing wrong?

Search method:

```
 public function autosearch($slug)
{
    if(mb_strlen($slug,'utf-8') > 1){
        $search = ' '.$slug;
        
        $searchLocale = $this->storeLocale->locale;
        if (Session::has('language') && $this->storeSettings->is_language)
        {
            $searchLocale = Language::find(Session::get('language'))->locale;
        }
        $prods = Product::byStore()->isActive();
        
        $prods = $prods->where(function($query) use($slug, $search, $searchLocale){
            $query->where('ref_code', 'like', "%{$slug}%")
            ->orWhereTranslationLike('name', "%{$search}%", $searchLocale)
            ->orWhereTranslationLike('name', "{$slug}%", $searchLocale);
        })->take(10)->get();
        return view('load.suggest',compact('prods','slug'));
    }
    return "";
}
```

Product slug in database:

```
fone-xiaomi-lxq6540vxj
```

Comment: can you show what `orWhereTranslationLike()` does

Comment: its because I have a product translation table which contains the name of the products, so If I need to query the name, must be from this table, not the product table.

Comment: there are two ways either you separate words using explode & - , or other method is to use full text search provided by mysql

Comment: you can even use the newly made [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scout) for full text search